# Need to make my Splash screen fits all the devices?

Tags: android

I need to make my splash screen fit all the devices. It works perfect on nexus but on other device the animation is a little bit different. Here is my splash screen activity. I think the problem is that axes Y and X will work different on other device

```
    logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);
    splashImg = findViewById(R.id.img);
    lottieAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.lottie);

    splashImg.animate().translationY(-2000).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);
    logo.animate().translationY(1100).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);
    lottieAnimationView.animate().translationY(1400).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);
```

and in the splash XML

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="731dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="411dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" >
       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           >
           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/img"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="900dp"
               android:src="@drawable/shafaqat"
               app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
               android:scaleType="centerCrop"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

               />

           <ImageView

               android:id="@+id/logo"
               android:layout_width="300dp"
               android:layout_height="300dp"
               android:src="@drawable/logo"
               app:layout_constraintVertical_bias=".1"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

           <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
               android:id="@+id/lottie"
               app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="200dp"
               app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
               app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/splash"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo" />
       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Don't hard code heights/widths ... `900dp` is too greedy

Comment: how much should i make it ?

Answer (score 0):

i would use weights and fill content views

if i want to all screen view, use fill-content in size attribute, and if you want your logo in the center, i used views with height attribute to spacing like bootstrap

i would put three views and each one with the same weight, and in the middle view i would put the image view with fill-content size, this is my way to make responsive views with the same resource keeping proportions

this is an example about how to use weights

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" />
```